# Disable all Samsung Stylus pen gestures (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Note)

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, stylus

When I hold the side button of my Samsung Galaxy Note's stylus pen pressed, it doesn't draw anymore but starts interpreting any stylus movement as a gesture (e.g. "go back", screenshot). Is there any chance to disable all gestures? Background: I have a drawing app that allows changing drawing mode when I hold the side button pressed. Until now pressing the button prevents the stylus from drawing but executing gesture actions.